# CSS sprite sheet animation in JSF

Tags: css, jsf, animation, sprite-sheet

I have this sprite sheet animation example in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/simurai/CGmCe/)
and I try to get this work in JSF.

I changed the CSS to load the image properly:

```
background-image: url("#{resource['images:sprite.png']}");
```

and in the JSF:

```
<img src="#{resource['images/sprite.png']}" />
<div class="hi"></div>
```

but the page shows only the sprite.png not the animated one.

With the Chorome Dev-Tools, it shows the div as 0px height element. When I change the settings it still isn't shwon... They are no further errors or warnings.

Update: 
The renderd HTML:

```
<img src="/t07/javax.faces.resource/images/sprite.png.jsf">
<div class="hi"></div>
```

Comment: Show what HTML is actually rendered, not your server-side source code

Comment: Updated with the renderd HTML.

Comment: "/t07/javax.faces.resource/images/sprite.png.jsf" seems like an invalid filename.

Comment: but this is the one that is renderd correctly. The problem is with that <div class="hi"> isn't showing the animation.

Comment: Are you streaming the image from the .jsf call? PNGs aren't animated. GIFs are.

Comment: Yes I'm streaming it. I know that PNGs aren't animated, I animate them via CSS, like in the jsfdidle example I posted.